Зацикленная проверка находиться ли кто в воисе Disnake
Делаю радио бота для дискорд на библиотеке Disnake и мне нужно делать каждые 30 секунд проверку находиться ли кто то еще в голосовом канале кроме бота, если нет то бот выходит
Код который написал не работает, помогите пожалуйста
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands, tasks
from database.sql import add_to_db, select_from_db

class Always(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.loop.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=30)
    async def loop(self, ctx):
        print("loop")
        guild = ctx.guild

        add_to_db(guild.id, "off")

        if select_from_db(guild.id) == "on": pass
        elif select_from_db(guild.id) == "off":
            voice_channel = guild.voice_client
            print(voice_channel)
            print(voice_channel.channel.members)
            if voice_channel and len(voice_channel.channel.members) == 1:
                await voice_channel.disconnect()
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Always(bot))

Это не рабочий код
